# How omnidirectional barcode scanner works algorithmically?

Tags: algorithm, barcode

I want to understand what is the most efficient algorithm invented so far for a omnidirectional barcode scanner. As I understood from this [description](https://www.denso-wave.com/en/adcd/fundamental/barcode/scan/index.html) there are multiple types of scanners. Most used in retail is CCD (Charge Coupled Device) with single line of red light. I kind of have a feeling I understand how it works when you hold the device in the hand and the light is perpendicular to the bars of the code. However on a warehouse line you need a very fast and humanless reading of barcode in any direction. I think that it uses similar to retail bar code but emits multiple lines of light (as in the picture). I wonder what is the most efficient algorithm to analyze the signal that is being collected and make a fast and error-prone decoding of barcode?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multidirectional barcode scanners use a single line, just like unidirectional barcode scanners. The core difference is that the line changes position with each scan, usually thanks to a rotating mirror.

So the actual algorithm is brute force - do a single line scanning in various positions until you hit the barcode pattern. The "various positions" part is implemented in hardware (the rotating mirror).